# How to pad a tensor with zeros in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

A really simple question here but I can't seem to figure this one out. As part of preparation to finals in Deep learning, I'm trying to solve questions from previous exams. I need to write a similar `Conv2d` method which
does stride and padding. My current code is:

```
class MyConv2d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=(1,1), stride=1, padding=0):
        # Set input as fields
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        self.p = kernel_size[0]
        self.q = kernel_size[1]
        self.stride = stride
        self.padding = padding
        self.kern = nn.Parameter(torch.rand((out_channels, in_channels, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1])))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.rand((out_channels,1)))
        
    def forward(self, X):
        X_clone = X.clone()
        h = int((X_clone.size(2) + (2 * self.padding) - self.p) / self.stride) + 1
        w = int((X_clone.size(3) + (2 * self.padding) - self.q) / self.stride) + 1
        result = torch.empty(X_clone.size(0), self.out_channels, h, w)
```

Test case:

```
batch_size = 3
H, W = 6,6
in_channels = 3
out_channels = 1
kernel_size = (2,2)
stride = 2
padding= 1
X = torch.rand(batch_size, in_channels, H, W)
conv = MyConv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels,kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding)
res = conv.forward(X)
```

The `forward` method should gave the same result as of `Conv2d`. The next step in `forward` method is padding with zeros but I can't seem to figure an easy way to pad `X_clone` with zeros. How it can be done?

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention that as part of the question, I'm not allowed to use any other methods under `nn`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you cannot use `torch.nn.functional.pad`, creating a new zero tensor and adding the original one to the desired position can be the way.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out other fancy methods except creating a new tensor and adding the original one to it.

This padding function could be helpful:

```
def zero_padding(input_tensor, pad_size: int = 1):
  h, w = input_tensor.shape  # assuming no batch and channel dimension
  pad_tensor = torch.zeros([pad_size*2 + h, pad_size*2 + w])
  pad_tensor[pad_size:pad_size+h, pad_size:pad_size+w] = input_tensor
  return pad_tensor
```

You can expand this function to work with inputs containing batch and channel dimensions, arbitrary padding, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to call `self._zero_padding(X_clone,self.padding)` but getting ": too many values to unpack (expected 2)". Do you know why?

Comment: In other words, I understand why I get this error, but how can I update `X_clone` which is of shape `[3, 3, 6, 6]`?